# Repository for publishing is not specified in multi-modules project with docker sbt

Tags: docker, multi-module, sbt-assembly, sbt-docker

I am trying to deploy a multi-modules project using an sbt-docker plugin. I want to create separate containers for api and app modules and to skip other modules. However, every time I run `docker: publish` I get such an error:

```
[error] (api/*:publishConfiguration) Repository for publishing is not specified.
[error] (app/*:publishConfiguration) Repository for publishing is not specified.
```

Here is my build.sbt file:

```
import sbt.Keys.publishTo

name := "project-name"

val globalSettings = Seq[SettingsDefinition](
  version := "1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
)

enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)

//.. other modules

val app = Project("app", file("app"))
  .enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
  .dependsOn(repositories)
  .settings(globalSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.11",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % "10.0.11" % Test,
      "de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-circe" % "1.18.0",
      "net.ruippeixotog" %% "scala-scraper" % "2.1.0"
    ),
    resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("hseeberger", "maven")
  )
  .settings(assemblyJarName in assembly := "app.jar")
  .settings(dockerfile in docker := {
    val artifact: File = assembly.value
    val artifactTargetPath = s"/app/${artifact.name}"

    new Dockerfile {
      from("java")
      add(artifact, artifactTargetPath)
      entryPoint("java", "-jar", artifactTargetPath)
    }
  },
    imageNames in docker := Seq(ImageName(s"name/dru-app"))
  )

val api = Project("api", file("api"))
  .enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
  .dependsOn(app)
  .settings(globalSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.11",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % "10.0.11" % Test,
      "de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-circe" % "1.18.0",
      "net.ruippeixotog" %% "scala-scraper" % "2.1.0"

    ),
    resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("hseeberger", "maven")
  )
  .settings(assemblyJarName in assembly := "api.jar")
  .settings(dockerfile in docker := {
    val artifact: File = assembly.value
    val artifactTargetPath = s"/api/${artifact.name}"
    publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("Unused transient repository", file("https://hub.docker.com/r/name/dru-api")))

    new Dockerfile {
      from("java")
      add(artifact, artifactTargetPath)
      entryPoint("java", "-jar", artifactTargetPath)
    }
  },
    imageNames in docker := Seq(ImageName(s"name/dru-api"))
  )


val root = Project("DRU-W3-FP-1-Toloka-Parser", file("."))
  .aggregate(app, api)
  .settings(
    publish := {},
    publishLocal := {},
    publishArtifact := false,
    publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("Unused transient repository", file("target/unusedrepo")))
  )
```

I would be very grateful for any advice on how to fix my build.sbt file to  publish it to docker hub!

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have two different problems for your subprojects `app` and `api`:

1) In `app`, it seems like you're missing a `publishTo` setting. I would expect to have one, as per [official SBT docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html).

2) In `api`, there is one `publishTo` but it is defined within the block `.settings(dockerfile in docker := {...})` so the value is not returned / assigned to your sub-project's setting. Try extracting it from there and setting up explicitly e.g. `.settings(publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("Unused transient repository"...)))` like as you do for the `root` project.

Hope that helps!